# Unable to build imebra in Xcode 12.4?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode12, imebra

Imebra is working in xcode 11.6, when trying to build in code 12.4, getting below error

*/Users/xxxxx/Imebra/imebra_for_ios/libimebra.a(imebra_exceptions.mm.o), building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS, file '/Users/xxxxx/Imebra/imebra_for_ios/libimebra.a' for architecture armv7*

can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.